# Could another player catch the Snitch?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

I know that if the Seeker was to catch the Snitch, that team would gain 150 points and the event would end the match.

But what happens if another player playing a different position sees the Snitch and catches it? Would it also end the game? Or would the player have to forfeit the Snitch and would it be re-released for the Seekers?

Comment: Related: [In Quidditch could the Seeker play other positions?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10136/in-quidditch-could-the-seeker-play-other-positions) — See the accepted answer there.

Comment: As far as I'm aware touching the snitch changes it permanently so it would need to be a *new* snitch. not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: @Pureferret Yes, they have "flesh memory", if I'm remembering the name correctly.  I remember reading somewhere that the witches/wizards who build Golden Snitches have to wear gloves so that their skin doesn't touch it.

Comment: @Izkata - I remember this too, but am having a hard time finding it in the books. It's not in *Quidditch Through the Ages* as far as I can tell, so it must be one of the main books. I just don't know which one. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Check the Deathly Hallows, (1) just after the scene where the Ministry official hands the Snitch to Harry, once he's gone, and (2) just before Harry figures out what to do with the Snitch.  (I forget if the events were as far apart as in the movie) - I have the strong feeling it was around there.

Comment: @Slytherincess: Izkata is right with (1), it's in _DH_, Chapter 7: '"Correct," said Scrimgeour. "A Snitch is not touched by bare skin before it is released, not even by the maker, who wears gloves."'

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I don't think another player ***MAY*** catch the Snitch. In *Quidditch Through the Ages*, page 29, it says:

> (FOUL) Snitchnip: All players but Seeker / Any player other than Seeker touching or catching the Golden Snitch

I'm correcting my original answer -- Yes, it appears it must be the Seeker to catch the Snitch.

Comment: I think you should change "can" to "may". Yes they CAN. No they aren't allowed. BTW, this is fairly obviously parallelled from soccer where only goalie is allowed to touch the football with his hands, IMHO

Comment: @DVK - Fixed it, Mr. Strunk & Bite! ;)

Answer (score 13):

What you're describing is a foul in Quidditch called a **Snitchnip**. It's defined as

> *Any player other than Seeker touching or catching the Golden Snitch*
>
> <sub><sup>[Quidditch Through the Ages](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quidditch_Through_the_Ages_(real))</sup></sub>

The implication is that interfering with the Snitch can cost you a *personal penalty*...

> The referee may award penalties against a team. The Chaser taking the
> penalty will fly from the central circle towards the scoring area. All
> players other than the opposing Keeper must keep well back while the
> penalty is taken.
>
> <sub><sup>[Quidditch Through the Ages](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quidditch_Through_the_Ages_(real))</sup></sub>

...but not a sending off.

> Down in the stands, Dean Thomas was yelling, ‘Send him off, ref! Red
> card!’ **‘This isn’t football, Dean,’ Ron reminded him. ‘You can’t send
> people off in Quidditch** – and what’s a red card?’
>
> ...
>
> ‘All right, all right. Flint nearly kills the Gryffindor Seeker, which
> could happen to anyone, I’m sure, so a penalty to Gryffindor, taken by
> Spinnet, who puts it away, no trouble, and we continue play,
> Gryffindor still in possession.’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</sup></sub>

And since the snitch (at least in competition play) has had its '*sense memory*' interfered with, a new snitch will need to be brought into play.

> ‘Correct,’ said Scrimgeour. **‘A Snitch is not touched by bare skin
> before it is released, not even by the maker, who wears gloves. It
> carries an enchantment by which it can identify the first human to lay
> hands upon it, in case of a disputed capture.**
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>